# Why this program does 35 percent accepted but rest is runtime errors?

Tags: c++

Once, when Dino was solving a problem related to arrays, he saw that the size of all arrays is at most 10<sup>6</sup>. Since Dino is a dinosaur, this number seemed very small to him. Therefore, he decided to create a big array.

Dino first creates an empty array and selects n pairs of numbers: (a1, b1), (a2, b2), ..., (an, bn). Then for each of these pairs he inserts into array the number bi ai times. For example,if the first pair is (3, 5), the number 5 will be inserted into array 3 times. After that, Dino decides to arrange this array in non-decreasing order, but since the array is very large, Dino's computer cannot perform this arrangement. He is interested in the k-th (the array is numbered starting from 1) number. Help Dino to find this number.
Input

First line contains number n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>). Each of the next n lines contains pair (ai, bi) (1 ≤ ai, bi ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>). The last line contains number k. It is guaranteed that k-th number exists in array.
Output

Print the k-th number in non-decreasing array.

INPUT
First line contains number n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>). Each of the next n lines contains pair (ai, bi) (1 ≤ ai, bi ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>). The last line contains number k. It is guaranteed that k-th number exists in array.

OUTPUT
Print the k-th number in non-decreasing array.

INPUT Examples

```
3
1 2
3 6
2 1
3
```

OUTPUT

`2`

I tried to code this my self but it got partially accepted. Can someone help me for doing this?

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<utility>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
using ull = unsigned long long;



int main()
{
  ull a, b, n, j, k;
  cin >> n;
  vector<ull> myvec;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin >> a >> b;
    for(j = 0; j < a; j++)
    {
      myvec.push_back(b);
    }
  }
  cin >> k;

  sort(myvec.begin(), myvec.end());

  cout << myvec[k - 1];
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to improve it (like telling us, in detail, what problems you have with your shown program, what input you give the program, what output you expected and what you actually got, etc.).

Comment: There is no question here, sorry buddy, but SO isn't for you to get someone to do work for you. Most olympiads release solutions for their problems after it is done. Maybe look on their website?

Comment: Our didn't release it for 4 months also i just want to see why me code is not accepted. They actually don't release it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is this enough?

Comment: Hint: You don't need to explicitely create the array. Sort the `b[]` array, keeping trace of the associated `a[]`multiplicity. A kind of counting sort at the end.

Comment: `#define ull unsigned long long` please do not do that. Macros (especially this one) are very dangerous. Here is safe replacement `using ull = unsigned long long;`

Comment: @MarekR Thanks for the tip. I will use 'using ull = unsigned long long'

Comment: The description says that there are at most 10^6 elements, but you only make room for 10^5.

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh, you are right. I didn't saw that. Now my 35 percent is accepted but rest of them are runtime errors.

Comment: Do not use C-array! Use `std::vector`. Your algorithm is to simple and as a result to slow. There is better way to quickly calculate result. Think if you can do this in more crafty way.

Comment: @walkthroughTV your title says nothing about the question. Like somebody already said, read the [ask] page.

Comment: @MarekR I did use vectors this time but same results. I edited the program

Comment: You don't need to recreate the array, and you don't need to sort anything (the description even tells you that you shouldn't: "Dino's computer cannot perform this arrangement"). Consider what happens if you turn the problem around; instead of `a[i]` being the `i`:th number, it tells you how many `i`s there are in total. Then consider that a linear search through 10^5 elements (bi ≤ 10^5) is faster than sorting 10^6 elements.

Comment: @molbdnilo When i use same code without sort the solution becomes 0% accepted.

Comment: @walkthroughTV Yes, it does. You need to represent the data in such a way that it doesn't need sorting, for instance in the way I described.

Comment: As an example, if you use the representation I described, the example would be represented as `{0,2,1,0,0,0,3,0,...`, where `...` is 99992 zeros.

Comment: @molbdnilo I didn't managed to code with your representation, could you show a little code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to recreate the array, and you don't need to sort anything (the description even tells you that you shouldn't: "Dino's computer cannot perform this arrangement").

Consider what happens if you turn the problem around slightly.

Instead of `a[i]` being the `i`:th number, let it say how many `i`s there are in total.
(The arrangement of the input hints at this, although not as obviously as the "sorting won't work" hint.)
This essentially makes a run-length encoded sorted array, with the indices of `a` doubling as elements, and the elements of `a` are the run lengths.

Then consider that a linear search through 10<sup>5</sup> elements (b<sub>i</sub> ≤ 10<sup>5</sup>) is way faster than sorting 10<sup>6</sup> elements.

Something like this:

```
int main()
{
    // Keeps track of the total number of occurrences of each number.
    // The values are all less than or equal to 100000.
    // Add an extra element to simplify the rest of the code.
    // (The zero will be unused.)
    std::vector<int> counts(100001);
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int count, value;
        cin >> count >> value;
        counts[value] += count;
    }
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    // Now go looking for the k:th number, adjusting k as we go.
    for (size_t number = 0; number < counts.size(); number++)
    {
        if (k <= counts[number])
        {
            std::cout << number << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        // Adjust k for the rest of the sequence.
        k -= counts[number];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @molbdnilo. It is 100% accepted now.

Comment: The good approach. But why a size of 100001 is the values are less than 105 ?

Comment: @Damien The power notation was broken when the description was pasted. 105 doesn't make a very interesting problem.